# Sine fourier transform $\frac{1}{2}i$ or $\frac{1}{2i}$

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a very short question concerning the fourier transform of a sine, for example this one: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformSine.html

In this example (and some others I've seen) they get $\frac{1}{2}i...$ however shouldn't this be $\frac{1}{2i}...$? I don't get why the $i$ doesn't stay in the denominator.

Maybe this is a realy trivial question, but help is enormously appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

$$
\frac{1}{2i}=-\frac{1}{2}i
$$

look at the sign!